# Double data in database

Tags: c#, web-services, webmethod

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string Login(string Username, string Password)
    {
        String result;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Nicole Wong\Desktop\Inari Tracking System\Inari Tracking System\App_Data\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Username, Password from UserData where Username = @Username AND Password = @Password", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        // Create an instance of DataSet.
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count> 0)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ActivityLog (CreateOn, CreateBy) VALUES (@CreateOn,@CreateBy)", con);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateOn", dt);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateBy", Username);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            // Create an instance of DataSet.
            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            da1.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();

            result = "Successful";
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            result = "Fail";
            return result;
        }
```

This is my simple web method to store user login time into database.

The problem is the data saved twice into the database. For example, I login into the system, then it returns successful, but I checked the database there is two same records saved with the same data. I run with breakpoint but the there is no any duplication, the code run nicely line by line.

Any idea? Thank you in advance

Comment: why are you using `SqlDataAdapter` and `ExecuteNonQuery` together for a same command?

Comment: I'm sorry actually I'm new to this, is there a problem while i using both? @un-lucky

Comment: @Alois yes, that is why you're getting duplication. the `.ExecuteNonQuery()` runs the insert once and then the `da1.Fill(ds);` runs the insert again. You do the same thing on your select by the way, you're executing both as queries and as nonqueries, when select is a query and insert is a nonquery.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks! It fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string Login(string Username, string Password)
{
    String result;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Nicole Wong\Desktop\Inari Tracking System\Inari Tracking System\App_Data\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Username, Password from UserData where Username = @Username AND Password = @Password", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
    //This us pretty much useless on a select, SELECT is a query, not a NonQuery
    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    // Create an instance of DataSet.
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count> 0)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ActivityLog (CreateOn, CreateBy) VALUES (@CreateOn,@CreateBy)", con);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateOn", dt);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateBy", Username);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //Don't use the DataAdapter and try to fill a dataset from an insert, all this insert will return is @@ROWCOUNT
        //SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1); 
        // Create an instance of DataSet.
        //DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        //da1.Fill(ds); 
        con.Close();

        result = "Successful";
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        result = "Fail";
        return result;
    }
```

You executed both your select and your insert twice, with the select it didn't matter so much, but with the insert it does. Remove the `.ExecuteNonQuery()` from the select and remove the `SqlDataAdapter` from the insert.

Comment: It fixed. Thanks a lot

Comment: If this solves your problem Alois, please accept the answer.